# Magento 2.3 How can add primary key constraint combination of multiple column using db_schema.xml?

Tags: magento2.3.5-p2, database-schema, db-schema

There are some custom tables in the database which don't have a primary key. A single column can not be a primary key. So I want to make a primary key with the help of existing two-column combinations.

I tried the below code:

```
 <table name="table_name" resource="default" engine="innodb">
        <constraint xsi:type="primary" referenceId="PRIMARY">
            <column name="rule_id"/>
            <column name="storeview_id"/>
        </constraint>
    </table>
```

But getting the error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: column in /vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/Declaration/SchemaBuilder.php on line 196
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unusual, but you can. The syntax of your db_schema.xml is correct, but you have to declare those column before using them in the **constraint** tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="table_name" resource="default" engine="innodb">
        <column xsi:type="int" name="rule_id" unsigned="true" nullable="false" identity="true" comment="Rule ID"/>
        <column xsi:type="int" name="storeview_id" unsigned="true" nullable="false" identity="false" comment="Store View ID"/>
        <constraint xsi:type="primary" referenceId="PRIMARY">
            <column name="rule_id"/>
            <column name="storeview_id"/>
        </constraint>
    </table>
</schema>
```

Remember it's mandatory that only one of the two columns can be set as AUTO_INCREMENT (**identity="true"**) and both must be not nullable (**nullable="false"**).
This is the resulting create statement

```
show create table table_name;  

CREATE TABLE `table_name` (
  `rule_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Rule ID',
  `storeview_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Store View ID',
  PRIMARY KEY (`rule_id`,`storeview_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

That should be what you expected.

*EDIT (after comment's suggestions)

If you want to add a primary key field on the existing table, this is the schema

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="table_name2" resource="default" engine="innodb">
        <column xsi:type="int" name="id" unsigned="true" nullable="false" identity="true" comment="ID"/>
        <column xsi:type="int" name="rule_id" unsigned="true" nullable="false" identity="false" comment="Rule ID"/>
        <column xsi:type="int" name="storeview_id" unsigned="true" nullable="false" identity="false" comment="Store View ID"/>
        <constraint xsi:type="primary" referenceId="PRIMARY">
            <column name="id"/>
        </constraint>
    </table>
</schema>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I am thinking to add new column "id" with primary key constraint. How can I make it first column in the table

Comment: Just put it first in the db_schema.xml file

Comment: Do I need to add existing column in db_schema.xml

Comment: No if you don't need to modify it. The declarative schema create the column if it doesn't exist, and modify it if it exists. Have a look at the documentation https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/db-schema.html

Comment: can you please give me an example with above 2 existing columns and new column 'id'?

Comment: Is the table already defined? Does it have a primary key?

Comment: no, primary key is not available. I want to add new column "id" and make it primary key

Comment: I edited the answer with the new id field

Comment: Thanks, I will let you know after implementing

Comment: thanks this is working but column added in the last

Comment: glad for you. Remove the table and recreate it, it should go in the first position. Vote the answer if it helped

Comment: voted, I think it shouldn't be a problem if the column(primary key) in the last